# init problems with PTKView in Swift

Tags: swift, stripe-payments

I am trying to add an init() ins swift so I can allocate PTKView at the top of the class so I can use it throughout my code.

I can create var PAymentVIew : PTKView in a function and it works fine but obviously not global.

So I created this at the top of the class :

```
class PaymentViewController: UIViewController , PTKViewDelegate {

    var PaymentView : PTKView
    var button   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton

    init(PaymentView : PTKView , button : UIButton) {
        self.PaymentView = PaymentView
        self.button = button

    }
```

All I get at the moment is an horrible error saying :

required initialiser 'init(coder)' must be provided by subclass of UIViewController.

Any ideas at all would be brilliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your vc:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

You're required to implement this initializer (thus the 'required' keyword).  If you don't want to support it, just leave the `fatalError` so people know.

```
init(PaymentView : PTKView , button : UIButton) {
    self.PaymentView = PaymentView
    self.button = button
    super.init()
}
```

Comment: Yes Logan I get this as help on XCODE but when I add this in , I get 'Super.init isn't called before returning from initlizer'

Comment: Yes, you need to add a super initializer somewhere to pass initialization down the line. I think just a basic `super.init()` would do for a VC.  I'm editing the answer currently.